# Automate a query across different servers without using a linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have the following query I put together from a stored procedure someone wrote at work and some SQL I found on the internet. It gets you all the disks on a server, free space and the free space in the database files on them in one query.

Problem is I've had trouble automating it and getting the apostrophes right isn't my strong point. Can someone help out adding openrowset to it. Ideally I want to have a table variable with a few servers in there and pass the server names down from it.

```
if exists ( select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    where o.xtype in ('U') and o.name in ('##DB_FILE_INFO' ))
drop table ##DB_FILE_INFO

if exists ( select * from tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
    where o.xtype in ('U') and o.name in ('##output'))
drop table ##output



create table ##DB_FILE_INFO (
[server_Name] varchar(255) not null,
[database_name] varchar(255) not null,
[File_ID]           int     not null,
[File_Type]     int     not null ,
[Drive]     varchar(255)    not null ,
[Logical_Name]      varchar(255)    not null ,
[Physical_Name]     varchar(255)    not null ,
[FILE_SIZE_MB]      int     not null ,
[SPace_USED_MB] int     not null ,
[Free_space]    int     not null ,
[Max_SIZE]      int     not null ,
[Percent_Log_growth_enabled]    int     not null ,
[growth_rate]   int     not null ,
[current_date]      datetime        not null
)
go
declare @sql    nvarchar(4000)
set @sql =
'use ['+'?'+']
--if db_name() <> N''?'' goto Error_Exit
 insert into ##DB_FILE_INFO
(
    [server_Name],
    [database_name],
    [File_ID],
[File_Type],
[Drive],
[Logical_Name],
[Physical_Name],
[FILE_SIZE_MB],
[SPace_USED_MB],
[Free_space],
[Max_SIZE],
[Percent_Log_growth_enabled],
[growth_rate],
[current_date]
)
SELECT 
@@servername as [Server_Name],
db_name() as database_name,
[file_id] AS [File_ID],
[type] AS [File_Type],
substring([physical_name],1,1) AS [Drive],
[name] AS [Logical_Name],
[physical_name] AS [Physical_Name],
CAST([size] as DECIMAL(38,0))/128. AS [File Size MB], 
CAST(FILEPROPERTY([name],''SpaceUsed'') AS DECIMAL(38,0))/128. AS 
[Space_Used_MB], 
(CAST([size] AS DECIMAL(38,0))/128) - 
 (CAST(FILEPROPERTY([name],''SpaceUsed'') AS DECIMAL(38,0))/128.) AS [Free 
 Space],
[max_size] AS [Max_Size],
[is_percent_growth] AS [Percent_Growth_Enabled],
[growth] AS [Growth Rate],
getdate() AS [Current_Date]
FROM sys.database_files'
exec sp_msforeachdb @sql
declare @svrName varchar(255)
declare @sql2 varchar(400)
--by default it will take the current server name, we can the set the server 
name as well
set @svrName = @@SERVERNAME
set @sql2 = 'powershell.exe -c "Get-WmiObject -ComputerName ' + 
QUOTENAME(@svrName,'''') + ' -Class Win32_Volume -Filter ''DriveType = 3'' | 
 select name,capacity,freespace | 
 foreach{$_.name+''
 |''+$_.capacity/1048576+''%''+$_.freespace/1048576+''*''}"'
--creating a temporary table
CREATE TABLE ##output
(line varchar(255))
--inserting disk name, total space and free space value in to temporary 
table
insert ##output
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql2;

with Output2 
--(drivename, capacity(gb),freespace(gb), always_on_status)
as
(
select @@servername as server_name, 
rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,1,CHARINDEX(':',line) -1))) as drivename
,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('|',line)+1,
(CHARINDEX('%',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('|',line)) )) as float)/1024,2) as 
'capacityGB'
,round(cast(rtrim(ltrim(SUBSTRING(line,CHARINDEX('%',line)+1,
(CHARINDEX('*',line) -1)-CHARINDEX('%',line)) )) as float) /1024 ,2)as 
'freespaceGB'
,CASE WHEN (SERVERPROPERTY ('IsHadrEnabled')=1) THEN 'YES' WHEN 
(SERVERPROPERTY ('IsHadrEnabled')=0) THEN 'NO'ELSE 'NOT AVAILABLE' END AS 
ALWAYS_ON_STATUS
--into #output2
from ##output
where line like '[A-Z][:]%'
--order by drivename
),
DB_FILE_INFO2 as
(
select server_Name,
    database_name,
    File_ID,
File_Type,
Drive,
Logical_Name,
Physical_Name,
FILE_SIZE_MB,
SPace_USED_MB,
Free_space,
Max_SIZE,
Percent_Log_growth_enabled,
growth_rate
--current_date 
from ##DB_FILE_INFO 
--inner join #output b on a.drive = b.drivename and a.server_Name = 
b.server_name
)
select  
getdate() as Today_Date,
a.server_Name,
a.database_name,
a.Drive,
a.Logical_Name,
a.Physical_Name,
a.FILE_SIZE_MB,
a.Space_Used_MB,
a.Free_space as Free_Space_in_File,
Percent_Free_space = a.Free_space/a.File_Size_MB,
 --Percentage_file_free = (a.Space_Used_MB/a.FILE_SIZE_MB),
b.capacitygb as Total_Drive_capacity,
b.freespacegb as Total_Free_Space,

a.Max_SIZE
from DB_FILE_INFO2 a
inner join output2 b on a.server_Name = b.server_name and a.Drive = 
 b.drivename
order by a.drive

--drop table ##DB_FILE_INFO
--drop table #output
```

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Are you getting an error when running your script? If so, what is it?

Comment: I tried adding the openrowset between inserting into my table variable and selecting from sys.database_files and get different syntax errors.